# JavaScript closures and class like implementation

Tags: javascript, closures

I've written the following code to understand class like implementations and closures in JavaScript.

## 1

```
function Person(name) {
    this.Name = name;
    console.log("Person Fired!!");
    
    (function EchoMyName(temp) {
        console.log("EchoMyName - " + temp);
    }("Self Called"));
    EchoMyName("Called by Person!");
}
Person.prototype.CallMe = function(){
    console.log("Call Me Fired!");
    EchoMyName("Called by CallMe!");
}
```

Here when I instantiate `Person`, I get the following **output** -

```
Person Fired!!
EchoMyName - Self Called
ReferenceError: EchoMyName is not defined
```

But it's right there, I defined it before I called it? Why the error?

## 2

Also when I modify the code to remove the previous errors and call `CallMe` on a person, it seems like it doesn't have access to EchoMyName

```
function Person(name) {
    this.Name = name;
    console.log("Person Fired!!");
    
    function EchoMyName(temp) {
        console.log("EchoMyName - " + temp);
    };
}
Person.prototype.CallMe = function(){
    console.log("Call Me Fired!");
    EchoMyName("Called by CallMe!");
}
```

**Call:**

```
new Person().CallMe();
```

**Output**

```
Person Fired!!
Call Me Fired!
ReferenceError: EchoMyName is not defined
```

**Update #1**

Thanks for all the answers. I found this link on Douglas Crockford's website:
http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

It provides a very clear understanding of information hiding in JavaScript.

Comment: In the first version, the `EchoMyName` name is scoped to the function itself, and isn't available in the enclosing scope. This is because it's a named function expression instead of a function declaration. In the second version, you're trying to invoke `EchoMyName` in a variable scope outside of that which it was created. The `.prototype` methods don't inherit variable scope of the constructor. ...and actually, the last defined function isn't valid syntax.

Comment: @CrazyTrain : Thanks corrected the syntax.

Comment: You should return the function..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Code Snippet #1

The reference error occurs because of the following code: `EchoMyName("Called by Person!");`

`EchoMyName` is a self-invoked function located inside the scope of a JavaScript constructor named `Person`. Once it is self-invoked, it no longer exists. If we were in another programming language, we could make an analogy to an anonymous object.

In JavaScript, functions are actually objects. When you declare a function, you are creating an instance of a [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) object.

Below are a few different ways of declaring a function.

```
//function statement
function x (a, b) { return a + b;  }

//function expression, this will store an anonymous function into a variable
var y = function (a, b) { return a + b;  };

//Function constructor 
var z = new Function ("a", "b", "return a + b;"); // avoid this form, it will prevent certain optimizations from the browser's JS engine because of the strings (this is just an example)
```

### Code Snippet #2

When you declare a variable or a function inside a JavaScript function, it is limited to the scope of the function. The same is true for a constructor.

You would need to declare a function expression and store it inside a property of the `Person` constructor.

Little example below.

```
function Person(name) {
    this.Name = name;
    console.log("1 Person Fired!!");

    // notice that function is stored in this.EchoMyName
    this.EchoMyName = function(temp) {  
       console.log("2 EchoMyName - " + temp);
    };

    console.log("3 Still in Person!")
}

Person p = new Person("Bob");
p.EchoMyName("Hello World!");
```

output:

```
1 Person Fired!!
3 Still in Person!
2 EchoMyName - Hello World!
```

### Prototypes

In JavaScript, there is no traditional inheritance like you would find in many other object oriented languages (C++, C#, Java). What you have instead is object chaining.

If we take your code in example, the Person constructor will have a shadowed object stored in a property named **prototype**. Each instance of Person will have a reference to the same prototype. Furthermore, the prototype of the prototype is Object.

I invite you to read the article [Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) from the Mozilla Developer Network for more information.

Answer (score 2):

```
(function EchoMyName(temp) {
    console.log("EchoMyName - " + temp);
}("Self Called"));
```

This is a function expression, not a function definition; the name `EchoMyName` only refers to the function inside the function itself, so you can’t use it later. (Except in IE’s JScript, which is buggy.)

Your second problem stems from the fact that what you have isn’t a class; it’s a function. It’s possible to declare a function inside a function in JavaScript, and it will be scoped to that function, just like a regular variable (but hoisted so it can be used at any point in the function). A prototype is just an object, and doesn’t have access to the local variables of the constructor.

To sum up, in ECMAScript 5:

- There are only three scopes:

  - Global
  - Function
  - `catch`
- In a named function expression, the name is only accessible by that function
- For a regular variable, there are no exceptions to the scope; functions on the prototype should use `this` if they need something of the target’s (and if they don’t, why are they on the prototype?)
- Without the parentheses, a function expression looks like a function declaration, which acts like a variable in the same scope, but is “hoisted” so that no matter where it appears in the function, it acts as if it had appeared at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

> But it's right there, I defined it before I called it? Why the error?

The difference is in how the `function` definitions are evaluated.

In the 1st snippet, `EchoMyName` is a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) due to the parentheses around it. These are allowed to be invoked immediately, but can only be referenced by their name within their own body.

In the 2nd, `EchoMyName` is instead a [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function). These are subject to [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet#Hoisting), allowing them to be referenced by their name outside of their own body.

> it seems like it doesn't have access to EchoMyName

This is because `EchoMyName` is bound to the scope inside `Person`. Beyond that, `EchoMyName` doesn't exist.

You'll either need to attach `EchoMyName` to the instance, either via `this` or `Person.prototype`, so that `CallMe` can reach it:

```
this.EchoMyName = function EchoMyName(temp) {
    console.log("EchoMyName - " + temp);
};
```

```
Person.prototype.EchoMyName = function EchoMyName(temp) {
    console.log("EchoMyName - " + temp);
};
```

```
Person.prototype.CallMe = function(){
    console.log("Call Me Fired!");
    this.EchoMyName("Called by CallMe!");
};
```

Or, if you want to keep `EchoMyName` scoped so it can't be called by other code, then `CallMe` needs to also be defined inside the same scoping `function`. Though, that doesn't necessarily have to be `Person`:

```
var Person = (function () {
    function Person(name) {
        this.Name = name;
        console.log("Person Fired!!");
    }

    function EchoMyName(temp) {
        console.log("EchoMyName - " + temp);
    }

    Person.prototype.CallMe = function () {
        console.log("Call Me Fired!");
        EchoMyName("Called by CallMe!");
    };

    return Person;
})();
```

Ref: [Revealing Module Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript)

Comment: This is very clear, thank you. But I have a doubt. If I use `this` to create `EchoMyName` it'll have access to the local variables inside `Person()` but if I define it as a prototype outside the `Person()` I don't have access to those local variables right? Does a prototype defined inside `Person()` have access to it's local variables?

Comment: @AbijeetPatro Methods on the `prototype` should be independent of any instances or closures related to them. So, you'll want to avoid altering the `prototype` from inside the constructor. If a method depends on the constructor as a closure, it can be defined there and attached to the instance (`this`) separate from other `prototype` methods. But, for methods that don't need the closure, the `prototype` should generally be preferred.